# how to extract part of string in RegEx

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have a string:

```
The estimated delivery time will be approximately 5 - 7 business days from the time of order.
```

I want to extract: `5-7 business days` from this string.

I wrote regex: `'(^[[0-9][-]]*.*$)'`

But it does not works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is a bit strange...

Try:

```
r'([0-9]+\s*-\s*[0-9]+) business days'
```

`^` and `$` are anchors and will match the beginning and end of the string, which I don't think is what you want here. Also, capture groups is not really necessary, so `r'[0-9]+\s*-\s*[0-9]+ business days'` should work just fine.

I added the quantifiers `+` just in case there are more business days. and `\s*` to provide for any possible spaces.

In your regex, you were having two character classes `[[0-9]` and `[-]` and a single literal `]` there.

The first character class will match any of `[`, or any number. The second will match a single hyphen.

The `r` at the front just makes the string become a raw string. It's usually safer to use raw strings in regexes.

Comment: @user2779095 Okay, added that in :)

Comment: @Eric OP just had it there so I kept it as well, because we can never know what OP intends to do. I also mentioned that it probably would work without parentheses a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search('approximately([\s\S]+business\s+days)',s).group(1)`. Grouping used to get desired result in regex match/search.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s="The estimated delivery time will be approximately 5 - 7 business days from the time of order."
re.search('\d+\s*\-\s*\d+.*days',s).group(0)
```